# Find position of element, then do something in jquery using .position() not working

Tags: jquery, scroll, gallery, image-gallery, css-position

I can not seem to find a way of jQuery understanding the current position of an element. I scroll through some markup using the html and css, jQuery below (like a gallery - but I dont want to use any plugins) but need to find the last and first positions so it does not continiually let someone scroll content off the page - currently I am just colouring the parent container when applying an action but will swap this out in live to not show or grey out the pagination/scroll buttons.

The scrolling works by adjusting by 209px or -209px just does not understand the position of first and last elements (li's). I am trying to stop the previous button working if there are no more previous li's and vice versa - like I said only colouring the parent for now for visual.
There could be any number of li's in this as they get dynamically spat out.
Attached fiddle URL too: http://jsfiddle.net/jambo/zLSUT/
Apologies for images not working in this demo.
So to recap - need to stop pagination in the direction where there will be no more content to view.
Hope that makes sense, thank you in advance.

css

```
    .smartH{
    float: left; position: relative;
    width:10000px; height: 80px; padding: 5px 0;
    font-family: arial;
    background: #fff;
    }
    .smartH a{
    float: left;
      text-decoration: none; cursor:pointer;
    }
    .smartH img{
    float: left;
    width: 100px; height: 80px;
    border: none;
    }
      .smartH .title{
     float: right;
      margin: 0 5px; width:90px;
    font-weight: bold; font-size: 13px; color: #000; line-height: 1.4; text-align: left;
    }
    .smartH .text{
    float: right;
    margin: 5px 5px 0; width:90px; 
    font-size: 12px; color: #000; line-height: 1.1; text-align: left;
    }

    .smartAd{
    float:left;
    width:627px; overflow: hidden;
     }

     .smartH li{
    position:relative;
    float:left; display: inline;
    height:80px; width:200px; padding:0 4px 0 5px;
    list-style-type: none;
     }
     .smartAd .paginate{
    float:right
     }
     .smartAd i{
    cursor:pointer;
    }
```

jQuery

```
    $( function () {
    var posF = $(".smartH li.first").position(); 
    var posL = $(".smartH li.last").position();     

    $("a#next").click( function () {
        $(".smartH li").stop().animate({
        left: "-=209px",
        }, 500 );
        if (posL.left == -627){
            $(".smartH").css("background", "blue");   
        }
        return false;
    });
    $("a#prev").click( function () {
        $(".smartH li").stop().animate({
        left: "+=209px",
        }, 500 );
        if (posF.left == 0){
           $(".smartH").css("background", "green");   
        }

        return false;
     }); 

    });
```

html

```
<div class="smartAd">
<ul class="smartH"><!-- posit abs?  -->
    <li class="first">
        <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://advertising.co.uk/wallpaper/blinds.gif" alt="blinds" />
            <p class="title">Call for a free quote today</p>
            <p class="text">Best value blinds in Lincolnshire!</p>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://advertising.co.uk/wallpaper/coach.gif" alt="coach" />
            <p class="title">Experience great days out</p>
            <p class="text">Great value coach trips</p>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://advertising.co.uk/wallpaper/coffee.gif" alt="coffee" />
            <p class="title">Need beans?</p>
            <p class="text">We have a great variety of beans at great prices</p>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://advertising.co.uk/wallpaper/creditcard.gif" alt="credit card" />
            <p class="title">Got bad credit?</p>
            <p class="text">We can help you boost your rating</p>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://advertising.co.uk/wallpaper/mobility.gif" alt="mobility" />
            <p class="title">Struggling to get around?</p>
            <p class="text">Great value scooters!</p>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="last">
        <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://advertising.co.uk/wallpaper/plumber.gif" alt="plumber" />
            <p class="title">Got a leak?</p>
            <p class="text">Ring for reliable and friendly plumbers</p>
        </a>
    </li>       
</ul><!-- // ul.smartH -->
<span class="paginate">
    <a href="" class="icon" id="prev">Prev 1-</a>
    <a href="" class="icon" id="next">- Next 1</a>      
</span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong sytax to specify first and last child, it should be:

```
var posF = $(".smartH li:first-child").position(); 
var posL = $(".smartH li:last-child").position();
```

If follows along the lines of CSS pseudo selectors.

Comment: sorry gave an older version on Fiddle, this one includes the classes in the li's.

Comment: Resolved: Added jsLint link to working copy - prev / next buttons are disabled if no more content available - works All versions of IE, Webkit and Geko.http://jsfiddle.net/jambo/eU3jk/13/

Comment: You should post an answer to your own post then, in case anyone in the future has the same problem.  Nothing wrong with posting an answer to your own question, I have done it in the past.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I used jQuery to move to the next sibling element by the amount of that elements width or height using jQueries "scrollTo" (all elements have a fixed outer size in the box model) then added the "animate" speed to transitiion this. Works great. I searched this on the web hard for a few days but could not get the resolve required. I hope the code enclosed is of a lot of use to others. I have tried to keep it a straight forward as possible - simple jQuery gallery with no plugins - shows 3 ads inline then scrolls to the next on click of prev / next buttons.
http://jsfiddle.net/jambo/eU3jk/13/

```
html
<!-- jamie paterson -->
<div class="smartAd">
<ul class="smartH">
<!-- posit abs? -->
<li>    
<a href="#">
<img src="http://advertising.co.uk/wallpaper/blinds.gif" alt="blinds" />
<p class="title">First Hampshire Rose</p>
<p class="text">For great value food with friends</p>
</a>
</li>
<li>    
<a href="#">
<img src="http://advertising.co.uk/wallpaper/coach.gif" alt="blinds" />
            <p class="title">Nara Sushi Restaurant</p>
            <p class="text">Healthy & appetising food</p>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li>    
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://advertising.co.uk/wallpaper/coffee.gif" alt="blinds" />
            <p class="title">Alexandra Sports</p>
            <p class="text">Running & fitness retailers</p>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li>    
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://advertising.co.uk/wallpaper/blinds.gif" alt="blinds" />
            <p class="title">Blades Barbers</p>
            <p class="text">£10 off Intensive Muscle Release</p>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li>    <a href="#">
            <img src="http://advertising.co.uk/wallpaper/coffee.gif" alt="blinds" />
            <p class="title">Aerial Connections</p>
            <p class="text">Audio & visual entertainment</p>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li>    
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://advertising.co.uk/wallpaper/coffee.gif" alt="blinds" />
            <p class="title">Highgrove Windows</p>
            <p class="text">10yr guarantee as standard</p>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li>    
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://advertising.co.uk/wallpaper/coach.gif" alt="blinds" />
            <p class="title">seven</p>
            <p class="text">Best value blinds in Lincolnshire!</p>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li>    
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://advertising.co.uk/wallpaper/blinds.gif" alt="blinds" />
            <p class="title">eight</p>
            <p class="text">Best value blinds in Lincolnshire!</p>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li>    
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://advertising.co.uk/wallpaper/blinds.gif" alt="blinds" />
            <p class="title">nine</p>
            <p class="text">Best value blinds in Lincolnshire!</p>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li>    
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://advertising.co.uk/wallpaper/coach.gif" alt="blinds" />
            <p class="title">Last</p>
            <p class="text">Best value blinds in Lincolnshire!</p>
        </a>

    </li>        
</ul>
<div class="nav">
    <button class="prev" title="previous"><</button>
    <button class="next" title="next">></button>
</div>
</div>
<!-- // smartAd -->

<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

<div class="smartAdV">
<ul class="smartV">
    <!-- posit abs? -->
    <li>    
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://advertising.co.uk/wallpaper/blinds.gif" alt="blinds" />
            <p class="title">First Hampshire Rose</p>
            <p class="text">For great value food with friends</p>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li>    
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://advertising.co.uk/wallpaper/coach.gif" alt="blinds" />
            <p class="title">Nara Sushi Restaurant</p>
            <p class="text">Healthy & appetising food</p>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li>    
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://advertising.co.uk/wallpaper/coffee.gif" alt="blinds" />
            <p class="title">Alexandra Sports</p>
            <p class="text">Running & fitness retailers</p>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li>    
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://advertising.co.uk/wallpaper/blinds.gif" alt="blinds" />
            <p class="title">Blades Barbers</p>
            <p class="text">£10 off Intensive Muscle Release</p>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li>    
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://advertising.co.uk/wallpaper/coffee.gif" alt="blinds" />
            <p class="title">Aerial Connections</p>
            <p class="text">Audio & visual entertainment</p>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li>    
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://advertising.co.uk/wallpaper/coffee.gif" alt="blinds" />
            <p class="title">Highgrove Windows</p>
            <p class="text">10yr guarantee as standard</p>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li>    <a href="#">
            <img src="http://advertising.co.uk/wallpaper/coach.gif" alt="blinds" />
            <p class="title">seven</p>
            <p class="text">Best value blinds in Lincolnshire!</p>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li>    
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://advertising.co.uk/wallpaper/blinds.gif" alt="blinds" />
            <p class="title">eight</p>
            <p class="text">Best value blinds in Lincolnshire!</p>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li>    
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://advertising.co.uk/wallpaper/blinds.gif" alt="blinds" />
            <p class="title">nine</p>
            <p class="text">Best value blinds in Lincolnshire!</p>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li>    
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://advertising.co.uk/wallpaper/coach.gif" alt="blinds" />
            <p class="title">Last</p>
            <p class="text">Best value blinds in Lincolnshire!</p>
        </a>

    </li>        
</ul>
<div class="nav">
    <span class="wrap">
        <button class="next" title="next">v</button>        
        <button class="prev" title="previous">^</button>
    </span>
</div>
</div>
<!-- // smartAdV -->

    css
    /* jamie paterson */
    /* start horizontal */
    .smartAd {
    float:left; position:relative; /* pos:rel for IE7 only when hasLayout init */
    width:627px; overflow:hidden;
    }
    .smartH {
    width:10000px; position:relative; float:left;
    height: 80px; padding: 0; margin:0;
    font-family: arial;
    background: #fff;
    }
.smartH img, .smartV img{
    float: left;
    width: 100px; height: 70px;
    border: none;
}
.smartH .title{
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px; width:100px;
    font-weight: bold; font-size: 13px; color: #000; line-height: 1.4; text-align: left;
}
.smartH .text{
    float: right;
    margin: 5px 5px 0; width:95px; 
    font-size: 12px; color: #000; line-height: 1.1; text-align: left;
}
.smartH a, .smartV a{
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none; cursor:pointer;
}
.smartH li {
    display: inline-block; float:left;
    width:205px; margin:0 4px 0 0; height: 70px; padding: 5px 0;
}
.smartAd .nav {
    float: right;
    width:33px; margin: 10px 0 0;
}
button{
    border: none; cursor: pointer;
    background-image:url("images/carousel-arrows.gif");
}
.prev{
    float: left;
    width:16px; height:16px; margin: 0 1px 0 0;
    background-position: 0 16px;
}
.next{
    float: right;
    width:16px; height:16px;
    background-position: 0 0;
}
/* end Horizontal Style */
/* start Vertical style */
.smartAdV {
    float:left; clear:left; position:relative; /* pos:rel for IE7 only when hasLayout init */
    height:616px; padding: 0 10px; overflow:hidden;
}
.smartV {
    width:100px; position:relative; float:left;
    height: 10000px; padding: 0; margin:0;
    font-family: arial;
    background: #ebebeb;
}
.smartV .title{
    float: left;
    margin: 8px 0; width:100px;
    font-weight: bold; font-size: 13px; color: #000; line-height: 1.4; text-align: left;
}
.smartV .text{
    float: right;
    margin: 5px 0 10px; width:100px; 
    font-size: 12px; color: #000; line-height: 1.4; text-align: left;
}
.smartV li {
    display: inline-block; float:left;
    width:100px; margin:0 0 8px; height: 180px; padding: 10px 0 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ebebeb; border-bottom:1px solid #ebebeb;
    background: #fff;
}
.smartAdV .nav {
    float: left; position:relative; left:-100px; bottom: -600px;
    width:100px; margin: 0;
    background:#fff;
}
.smartAdV .wrap{
    float: right;
    width:33px;
}
.smartAdV .prev{
    float: left;
    width:16px; height:16px; margin: 0 1px 0 0;
    background-position: 16px 0;
}
.smartAdV .next{
    float: right;
    width:16px; height:16px;
    background-position: 16px 16px;
}
jQuery
// jamie paterson //
//adding classes via jQuery instead of direct for ease - some of these variables not used as var's
var currentElement = $(".smartH li:first"); // sets first current horiz
var lastElementThree = $(".smartH").children("li").eq(-3).addClass("lastThird"); //horiz
var firstElementOne = $(".smartH").children("li").eq(0).addClass("firstOne"); //horiz
var currentElementV = $(".smartV li:first"); // sets first current vert
var lastElementThreeV = $(".smartV").children("li").eq(-3).addClass("lastThirdV"); //vertical
var firstElementOneV = $(".smartV").children("li").eq(0).addClass("firstOneV"); //vertical
var prevBtn = $(".smartAd .prev, .smartAdV .prev").prop('disabled', true).css({ opacity: 0.5 }); // hide but show on scroll
// HORIZONTAL section
$(".smartAd .prev").click(function () {
    currentElement = currentElement.prev();
    scrollTo(currentElement);
    $(currentElement).nextAll().slice(2, 3).css("display", "none"); //move back one place/element and hide prev li
    $(".smartAd .next").prop('disabled', false).css({ opacity: 1.0 }); 
    $(".smartH").stop().animate({
        left: "+=209px" // block li's are white space dependent 
        }, 500 );
    e.preventDefault();
});
$(".smartAd .next").click(function () {
    currentElement = currentElement.next();
    scrollTo(currentElement);
    $(currentElement).nextAll().slice(0, 2).css("display", "inline-block");//move on one place/element and show next li
    $(".smartAd .prev").prop('disabled', false).css({ opacity: 1.0 }); 
    $(".smartH").stop().animate({
        left: "-=209px" // block li's are white space dependent
        }, 500 );
    e.preventDefault();
});
// VERTICAL section
$(".smartAdV .prev").click(function () {
    currentElementV = currentElementV.prev();
    scrollTo(currentElementV);
    $(currentElementV).nextAll().slice(2, 3).css("display", "none"); //move back one place/element and hide prev li
    $(".smartAdV .next").prop('disabled', false).css({ opacity: 1.0 }); 
    $(".smartV").stop().animate({
        top: "+=200px" // block li's are white space dependent 
        }, 500 );
    e.preventDefault();
});
$(".smartAdV .next").click(function () {
    currentElementV = currentElementV.next();
    scrollTo(currentElementV);
    $(currentElementV).nextAll().slice(0, 2).css("display", "inline-block");//move on one place/element and show next li
    $(".smartAdV .prev").prop('disabled', false).css({ opacity: 1.0 }); 
    $(".smartV").stop().animate({
        top: "-=200px" // block li's are white space dependent
        }, 500 );
    e.preventDefault();
});
    function scrollTo(element) { // includes/combined horiz and vert - left action and top action respectively
        if ($(currentElement).hasClass("lastThird")){
           $(".smartAd .next").prop('disabled', true).css({ opacity: 0.5 }); 
           $(window).scrollLeft(element.position().left);
        }
        else if ($(currentElement).hasClass("firstOne")){
           $(".smartAd .prev").prop('disabled', true).css({ opacity: 0.5 });
           $(window).scrollLeft(element.position().left);
        } 
        else{
        $(window).scrollLeft(element.position().left);
        }        
        if ($(currentElementV).hasClass("lastThirdV")){ // vert
           $(".smartAdV .next").prop('disabled', true).css({ opacity: 0.5 });
           $(currentElementV).children().scrollTop(element.position().top);
        }
        else if ($(currentElementV).hasClass("firstOneV")){ // vert
           $(".smartAdV .prev").prop('disabled', true).css({ opacity: 0.5 });
           $(currentElementV).children().scrollTop(element.position().top);
        } 
        else{ // vert
            $(currentElementV).children().scrollTop(element.position().top);
        }
    }
```